# Detect when a view is removed from the page using Backbone.js or Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

using Backbone.js with Marionette.js (Go Derick Bailey!). Need to detect when a view is removed from the page. Specifically, I'm overwriting it with another view.

Is there an event I can detect of function I can overload to detect when this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: the combination of fencliff and Hurricanepkt's answers is what you want... use a region to manage the view being displayed within a DOM element, and listen for the "close" event, or use the `onClose` callback when needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Marionette provides the [`View.onClose`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-close) method for this purpose:

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  onClose: function(){
    // custom cleanup or closing code, here
  }
});
```

In vanilla Backbone you can override the `View.remove` method:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  remove: function(){
    // custom cleanup or closing code, here

    // call the base class remove method 
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

Neither of these methods will work if you are simply clobbering the view's DOM element.  If that is your case, the solution is simple: Don't do that. Remove the previous view explicitly before rendering another view in its place.

Comment: Seems like onClose has been replaced with onBeforeDestroy - https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-onbeforedestroy

Answer (score 2):

The region show function is going to do most of what you are looking for

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#basic-use

And look at the on show event later in the page